# How to remove straight line from multiple routes on Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my application,I need to display of Map and alternative routes between source and destination using Google mapV2 API.
The only problem is, while displaying multiple routes on the map by setting alternatives=true, one straight comes along with the correct routes. I want to get rid of that straight line between source and destination.

Here is my GMapV2GetRouteDirection code,

```
public class GMapV2GetRouteDirection {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV2GetRouteDirection() { }

public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving&alternatives=true";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my method which returns the route,

```
private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String response = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading route...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Get All Route values
        document = v2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(fromPosition,
                toPosition, GMapV2GetRouteDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
        response = "Success";
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = v2GetRouteDirection
                    .getDirection(document);
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(8)
                    .color(Color.BLUE);


            /*for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.addAll(directionPoint.get(i));
            }*/
            // Adding route on the map
            rectLine.addAll(directionPoint);
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
            //markerOptions.position(toPosition);
            //markerOptions.draggable(true);
            //mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
```

Comment: Iterate trough the resulsts and remove if it has only 2 LatLngs

Comment: When I set alternatives= false,it doesn't give any straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wedak balagena inna moda prashna danne nethuwa